# Is there a package or other convenient means of keeping a research diary for a RStudio project?

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown, journal

I'm embarking on an ambitious RStudio project, one that's similar to Jack Dougherty's [On the Line](https://ontheline.trincoll.edu/) collaborative book-in-progress about Hartford. I'm finding I need to keep several different kinds of notes: on the research itself, on my R coding, on how to use certain tools, on my configurations, etc.

Initially, I just want to keep a diary focused on the background technology: how I configured the RStudio project itself, what packages I installed, why I started to use Packrat but then deleted the project and started over, that [bookdown](https://www.bookdown.org/) needs certain yaml fields in its index.Rmd file to work properly (took me a day to find this out), and so on. I figured I can't be the first person to have a need for record-keeping like this.

So I started by looking for an R package, an RStudio addin, or a R Markdown template or literate programming that could insert dated entries, maybe handle tags, etc. Having no luck, I started to learn about the [blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) package.

Soon I decided this is overkill. While I probably should start a blog about the book's subject (the crisis triggered by the coronavirus), this would not be the place to keep records of subjects like how to make bookdown work with a non-standard directory structure. Also, blogdown wants its own project directory, which sort of breaks the connection to the original project. (The blog and research project subdirectories do share a common parent, but this seems awfully kludgy.)

So I came back to the idea of including this diary in the original bookdown project. But I know no other way to do this than with an Rmd file, which (I think) cannot automatically insert accurate date-time stamps in individual posts, use tags, etc. Since I'm so new to some of this stuff, I'm writing here to ask those of you with more experience, "What's the best way to meet this common need?" Can you recommend any tools that will serve this purpose well?

Comment: From what you describe, it sounds like you might just want to use Jekyll with [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com). It can be [integrated with R-Studio](https://resources.github.com/whitepapers/github-and-rstudio/), too, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about using a repo with Git?  That could address the need for tracking code  with maximum simplicity...as long as you commit frequently!  Still it doesn't address the bigger picture, sorry